# Makefile does not recognize pattern rule

Tags: makefile

I'm really struggling in understanding why the following makefile won't work:

```
all: buildFolders main.out
   mv main.out build/
   -echo "File compiled"

buildFolders:
   mkdir -p build src
   cp *.c src/

%.s: %.c
   gcc -S $< -o $@


%.out: src/%.s
   gcc $< -o $@
```

It is executed in a folder containing only the makefile and a main.c file. It should build the *src* and *build* folder, copy the *main.c* in the *src* folder and then start compiling the *main.out*. Unfortunately it throws the error "no rule to make target 'main.out'". Since I have the %.out that matches 'main.out' I don't see why it gives me that error. Instead it should look for the src/main.s file, create it and then use it to generate the main.out.
What am I doing wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a number of problems.

First, listing prerequisites in order doesn't create a dependency relationship.  If, for example, you ever wanted to enable parallel builds then this:

```
all: buildFolders main.out
```

doesn't force the `buildFolders` target to be built before `main.out`.  These two targets both must be built before `all` but this doesn't tell make that there's any relationship between `buildFolders` and `main.out`.  If `buildFolders` must be completed before `main.out` can be built then `main.out` must list `buildFolders` as a prerequisite.

Second, you haven't told make how to build a file `src/main.c`.  It's built as a side-effect of the `buildFolders` target, but make can't know that.  You need to explain to make that this file can exist.  I recommend adding a rule:

```
src/%.c: %.c
        mkdir -p src
        cp $< $@
```

and removing the `buildFolders` target altogether.

However, I really question why you want to do this anyway.  What's the point of copying the source files in the current directory to some sub-directory to build them?  It's dangerous and confusing to have multiple copies of source files lying around because they can get out of sync with each other, then you're building older versions and you spend hours trying to understand why something doesn't work.  It's a *really* bad idea.

Comment: It's a makefile to demonstrate what a makefile can do. I'll get rid of the double source file because, as you pointed out, it's a bad idea. Many thanks.